# Equivalent of BlueBird Promise.props for ES6 Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I would like to wait for a map of word to Promise to finish. BlueBird has Promise.props which accomplishes this, but is there a clean way to do this in regular javascript? I think I can make a new object which houses both the word and the Promise, get an array of Promises of those objects, and then call Promise.all and put them in the map, but it seems like overkill.

Comment: I take it your `Map` has values that are promises? If I understand the question correctly, `Promise.all(map.values())` ? If that's wrong, can you at least show the "object" you are dealing with and how it is "created"

Comment: Show us the code for what you're starting with (like perhaps the object that has promise properties) and explain what you're trying to accomplish.  We can't help you in any specific way without some level of detail.

Comment: What does "word" mean?

Comment: "word" is just a string. If I wait on Promise.all(map.values()), the next "then()" will only have access to the values and not the keys. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: if you are OK with converting that map to a regular object you can use the `async-q` library

Answer (score 3):

I have two different implementations using ES6 async functions:

```js
async function PromiseAllProps(object) {
    const values = await Promise.all(Object.values(object));
    Object.keys(object).forEach((key, i) => object[key] = values[i]);
    return object;
}
```

One line shorter, but less optimized:

```js
async function PromiseAllProps(object) {
    const values = await Promise.all(Object.values(object));
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(object).map((prop, i) => ([prop, values[i]])));
}
```

### Example

```js
const info = await PromiseAllProps({
    name: fetch('/name'),
    phone: fetch('/phone'),
    text: fetch('/foo'),
});

console.log(info);
```

```
{
    name: "John Appleseed",
    phone: "5551234",
    text: "Hello World"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An implementation of Bluebird.props that works on plain objects:

```js
/**
 * This function maps `{a: somePromise}` to a promise that
 * resolves with `{a: resolvedValue}`.
 * @param {object} obj
 * @returns {Promise<object>}
 */
function makePromiseFromObject(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  return Promise.all(values)
    .then(resolved => {
      const res = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
        res[keys[i]] = resolved[i];
      }
      return res;
    })
}
```

Comment: It's not a built-in, per-se, but if OP's intention was to avoid adding library this is the best answer (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with values that are promises (or a mix of promises and non-promises) - and you want the final resolved value to be a `Map` with all values resolved

```
const mapPromise = map => 
    Promise.all(Array.from(map.entries()).map(([key, value]) => Promise.resolve(value).then(value => ({key, value}))))
    .then(results => {
        const ret = new Map();
        results.forEach(({key, value}) => ret.set(key, value));
        return ret;
    });
```

Although, I bet someone has a slicker way to do this, some of the new ES2015+ stuff is still new to me :p

Answer (score 1):

The venerable [async.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library has a promisified counterpart: [async-q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-q)

The promisified `async-q` library supports all the functions in the `async` library. Specifically `async.parallel()`. At first glance `async.parallel()` looks just like `Promise.all()` in accepting an array of functions (note one difference, an array of **functions**, not **promises**) and run them in parallel. What makes `async.parallel` special is that it also accepts an object:

```
const asyncq = require('async-q');

async function foo () {
    const results = await asyncq.parallel({
        something: asyncFunction,
        somethingElse: () => anotherAsyncFunction('some argument')
    });

    console.log(results.something);
    console.log(results.somethingElse);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative implementation combining ES6+ Object.entries() and Object.fromEntries():

```
async function pprops(input) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        await Promise.all(
            Object.entries(input)
                .map(
                    ([k, p])=>p.then(v=>[k, v])
                )
        )
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be advisable to use a library like bluebird for this. If you really want to do this yourself, the main idea is to:

- Resolve each of the map values and connect the promised value back with the corresponding key
- Pass those promises to `Promise.all`
- Convert the final promised array back to a Map

I would make use of the second argument of `Array.from`, and the fact that an array of key/value pairs can be passed to the `Map` constructor:

```js
Promise.allMap = function(map) {
    return Promise.all( Array.from(map, 
        ([key, promise]) => Promise.resolve(promise).then(value => [key, value])
    ) ).then( results => new Map(results));
}

// Example data
const map = new Map([
    ["Planet", Promise.resolve("Earth")],
    ["Star", Promise.resolve("Sun")],
    ["Galaxy", Promise.resolve("Milky Way")],
    ["Galaxy Group", Promise.resolve("Local Group")]
]);

// Resolve map values
Promise.allMap(map).then( result => console.log([...result]) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write it using Promise.all + reduce

```
const promiseProps = (props) => Promise.all(Object.values(props)).then(
      (values) => Object.keys(props).reduce((acc, prop, index) => {
         acc[prop] = values[index];
         return acc;
      }, {})
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

And a nice lodash variant for sake of completeness for plain js objects

```
async function makePromiseFromObject(obj: {[key: string]: Promise<any>}) {
    return _.zipObject(Object.keys(obj), await Promise.all(Object.values(obj)))
}
```