# Output results of two promises into a single object

Tags: javascript, promise

I have two asynchronous functions which create promises. Both functions use the same input `i`.

```
async function1(i) {}
async function2(i) {}
```

I will be calling these functions multiple times with different values for my input, and I want to make my code as efficient as possible, so I want to queue the promises and have them run in parallel using `Promise.all()`.

However, I want to get a single result as my final output, which will be an array of objects like so:

```
[
  {
    input: i,
    result1: result1,
    result2: result2
  },
  ...
]
```

I have accomplished this in two descrete steps:

```js
async function function1(i) {
  return i * i
}

async function function2(i) {
  return i * i * i
}

async function main() {
  var promises = []

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let promise = function1(i)
      .then(function(result1) {
          return {i:i, result1:result1}
      });

    promises.push(promise)
  }

  var final = await Promise.all(promises)
  
  var promises2 = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let promise = function2(i)
    .then (function(result2) {
      final[i]['result2'] = result2;
    });
    
    promises2.push(promise);
  }
  
  await Promise.all(promises2)
  
  console.log(final)

}

main()
```

However, I feel like this can be accomplished using a single `Promise.all()`. Can you tell me how?

Comment: `let array3 = array1.concat(array2)`

Comment: I would do this with `promises1` and `promises2` before calling `Promise.all()`?

Comment: `await Promise.all(promises1.concat(promises2))`, or just push all the `function2` promises onto `promises1` instead of having a second array.

Comment: consider using bluebird Promise.props.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600771/equivalent-of-bluebird-promise-props-for-es6-promises

Comment: Thanks for your comments, however I have not been able to get it to work. I have updated my post to include a running sample, with the final result I want. However my guess is that the code is not efficient. My goal is to learn how to make this more efficient (Reduce to 1 loop, run only 1 `Promise.all()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
async function function1(i)
{
    return i * i
}

async function function2(i)
{
    return i * i * i
}

async function main()
{
    const promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        promises.push(function1(i), function2(i));

    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    const data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        const [result1, result2] = results.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2);
        data.push({ i, result1, result2 });
    }

    console.log(data);
}

main();
```

This should work smoothly and quickly. The functions `function1` and `function2` return `Promise`s if you do not `await` them, so pushing them onto the `promises` array is self-explanatory.

Then you await `Promise.all`, which waits until all 20 promises that were fired off have completed. Finally, the second loop runs through the promises that were returned.

In my code I used [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). I assume those are available to you since you are using async functions, which implies that you can use ES2017.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I think my solution solves the problem in 1 loop. Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: Your solution involves 2 places where `Promise.all` is being called: first inside of the loop, and then outside of it. This means that you are waiting for pairs of promises to complete, and then waiting on that wait for each of the pairs to complete. I don't know how much performance you require, but this is probably a bottleneck.

Comment: You're right about that, but once you `await` such a packaged promise, it incurs overhead. When you await an array of packaged promises, it's like having to open boxes that are inside of boxes. Therefore, you want to do this as few times as possible.

Comment: You are correct, I see that in my network traces there are two separate queues happening. Let me play with your answer, thanks for talking to me.

Comment: Just implemented it, and it is certainly more efficient. I still hate having to run a second loop to restructure the linear array of promises, but I guess that is just what you have to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 333's answer is correct, not mine. This solution will have 2 batches in the queue.

I think I figured it out:

```js
console.log("start")

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function function1(i) {
  await sleep(2000);
  return i * i
}

async function function2(i) {
  await sleep(2000);
  return i * i * i
}

async function main() {
  var promises = []

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let a = function1(i);
    
    let b = function2(i);
    
    let promise = Promise.all([a,b]).then(
      function([resulta,resultb]) {
          return {i:i, result1: resulta, result2: resultb}
      });

    promises.push(promise)
  }

  var final = await Promise.all(promises)
  
  
  console.log(final)

}

main()
```

Note that I added a sleep function to test the parallelization of these functions. Everything runs in 2 seconds, so I think it is optimized.